# Set linearLayout margin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I need to fill a LinearLayout (child of a ScrollView) with dynamic TextViews.

The problem is that, in my app, the position where the scroll starts is not defined (it changes dynamically while using the app) and I think I've resolved this with `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`.

The main problem is that I need the ScrollView to end at 90dp from the bottom. But I cannot do that with margins (as in my code below) cause it ignores them.

I've also tried padding but doesn't work too.

This is my solution that doesn't work:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_seguiti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_seguiti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="90dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I really need that margin cause at the bottom there are some buttons.
As asked, this is my full xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout_seguiti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Cerca utenti da seguire"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Cerca..." />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tableLayout_seguiti">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Utenti che segui"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Clicca sul nome degli utenti che desideri seguire o smettere di seguire."
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_seguiti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_view_seguiti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_mieiPost"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="I miei post"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_home"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_seguiti"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:text="Seguiti"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_home" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_home"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:text="Home"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_seguiti"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_mieiPost"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set margin only for scroll view. Remove the margin from the linear layout.
Add **full viewport: true** for scroll view.

Comment: android:fillViewport=true;

Comment: I've set margind only for scroll and also add android:fillViewport=true but it still ignores the bottom margin.

Answer (score 0):

make height of scrollView `match_parent` this may help check below

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll_seguiti"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_view_seguiti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="90dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if I make it match_parent, the view start at the top of everything, instead I want it to start at the bottom of "scroll_view" as seen in app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scroll_view"

Comment: share whole layout xml